# TapeEquilibrium - codility - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

## Problem

A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given. Array A represents numbers on a tape.

Any integer P, such that 0 < P < N, splits this tape into two non-empty parts: A[0], A[1], ..., A[P − 1] and A[P], A[P + 1], ..., A[N − 1].

The difference between the two parts is the value of: |(A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[P − 1]) − (A[P] + A[P + 1] + ... + A[N − 1])|

In other words, it is the absolute difference between the sum of the first part and the sum of the second part.

For example, consider array A such that:

```
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 2
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 3
```

We can split this tape in four places:

```
P = 1, difference = |3 − 10| = 7
P = 2, difference = |4 − 9| = 5
P = 3, difference = |6 − 7| = 1
P = 4, difference = |10 − 3| = 7
```

Write a function:

function solution(A);

that, given a non-empty array A of N integers, returns the minimal difference that can be achieved.

```
For example, given:

  A[0] = 3
  A[1] = 1
  A[2] = 2
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 3
the function should return 1, as explained above.
```

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [2..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [−1,000..1,000].

## My solution:

```js
A = []
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 2
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 3

function solution(A) {
  // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)

  if (A.length > 0) {
    let defArr = [];
    let l = [];
    let all = A.reduce((a, b) => {
      l.push(a)
      return a + b
    })

    l.forEach((item) => {
      defArr.push(Math.abs(all - (item + item)))
    })
    return Math.min(...defArr)
  }

  return 0;

}
console.log(solution(A))
```

Comment: Will the person that down voted this question please provide a comment explaining why.

Comment: I thought this is for code review, and I'm a junior on that field, So I'm looking for the experts reviewing my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logically, the code looks correct but from performance perspective, there are few things that can be improved. Let's look at the 2 points:

- **Time Complexity: O(n)** - 1 loop, 1 reduce and 1 Math.min. All run in O(n) time.
- **Space Complexity: O(n)** - Two arrays - defArr and l which have size n

There is `nothing can be done for time complexity` but `space complexity can be reduced to constant space`. No need to have additional arrays. One can simply loop and store intermediate values in temporary variables.

I have re-written the same. Inside the loop, at each *index*, the difference is calculated and compared to a *min* variable. If the new min is lesser than existing one; then update min otherwise do next iteration.

```js
A = []
A[0] = 3
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 2
A[3] = 4
A[4] = 3

function solution(A) {
  let sum = A.reduce((total, value) => total + value, 0)
  let min = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
  let cumulativeSum = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < A.length - 1; ++i) {
    cumulativeSum = cumulativeSum + A[i]
    sum = sum - A[i]
    diff = Math.abs(sum - cumulativeSum)
    if (diff < min) {
      min = diff
    }
  }
  return min
}

console.log(solution(A))
```

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how much if affects performance (haven't measured), but one could return the solution in a couple of edge cases without going into the `for` loop every time:

```
function solution(A) {
    // If there are only two items in the array, return their difference
    if (A.length === 2) Math.abs(A[0] - A[1]);

    // If every item in the array is the same
    if (A.every((item) => item === A[0])) {
        // If length is even, return zero, else return the item as that will be the difference
        (A.length % 2) === 0 ? 0 : A[0];
    }

    // ... rest of the solution from the accepted answer above

}
```